# Add null byte every X byte in c++

Tags: c++, winapi, byte

Hi for my project i need to add null byte every x byte in a char array like

```
unsigned char data[] = {
0x98, 0xB0, 0x26, 0x7E, 0x11, 0x80, 0x9A, 0x79, 
0xE7, 0x46, 0x14, 0xA4, 0x62, 0x7E, 0x06, 0xC0 ...
};
```

Need to be:

```
unsigned char data[] = {
0x98, 0xB0, 0x26, 0x7E, 0x00, 0x11, 0x80, 0x9A, 0x79, 0x00 
0xE7, 0x46, 0x14, 0xA4, 0x00, 0x62, 0x7E, 0x06, 0xC0, 0x00...
};
```

i need a function in pure winapi no std::string im trying so many thing but im stuck 
Thank to help me if you can ! :)

Comment: Show the code you have tried so far. This should be a very simple loop.

Comment: And why can't you use things from the standard library?

Comment: There's no single function for this. Bear in mind that you need more space to store the array with inserted bytes, so you'll have to allocate it first. Oh, and WinAPI is not about string handling in general.

Comment: Because Winapi is *so* PURE!

Comment: Yes so pure :) and so light i need small exe size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will do what you want on a new array allocated on heap:

```
unsigned char* Process(const unsigned char* buffer, size_t size, size_t noChars, size_t& newSize)
{
   newSize = size + size/noChars;
   unsigned char* bufferProcessed = new unsigned char[newSize];

   size_t i;
   for (i = 0; i < size/noChars; ++i)
   {
       memcpy(bufferProcessed+(noChars+1)*i, buffer+noChars*i, noChars);
       bufferProcessed[(noChars+1)*(i+1)-1] = '\0';
   }
   if (size%noChars)
       memcpy(bufferProcessed+(noChars+1)*i, buffer+noChars*i, size-noChars*i);

   return bufferProcessed;
}
```

And this one does the reverse (notice the changes!):

```
unsigned char* ProcessBack(const unsigned char* buffer, size_t size, size_t noChars, size_t& newSize)
{
    newSize = size - size/noChars;
    unsigned char* bufferProcessed = new unsigned char[newSize];

    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < size/noChars; ++i)
    {
        memcpy(bufferProcessed+noChars*i, buffer+(1+noChars)*i, noChars);
    }
    if (size%noChars)
        memcpy(bufferProcessed+noChars*i, buffer+(1+noChars)*i, size-noChars*i);

    return bufferProcessed;
}
```

Comment: it seems to walk very well thank you, can i do the same trick but in reverse to simply remove the null bytes every x ?

thank @Liviu